# What is the equivalent linux command in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I am trying to merge all the files in Windows batch, then sort all the rows and filter only based on unique rows as header can be repeated many times. I ever used linux and in linux this command is just this however I am not sure how can I do the same in windows bash,

```
sed 1d *.csv | sort -r| uniq  > merged-file.csv
```

Comment: This is not a Linux command, these are gnu commands. GNU environment also can be reached in windows.

Comment: the closes you will get is with the powershell `get-content Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: ... or Cygwin :-)

Comment: @Dominique Yes, but powershell is the only real "do not need to install" windows tool :)

Comment: @IporSircer thx for your command,  I've tired to do the same in window, but uniq didn't work, do u know what can I write instead of it?

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard can u plz explain what is get-content Sort-Object -Unique, I am not familiar with bash, starting to learn , thx

Comment: it is not bash, it is powershell.

Comment: You are not make any sense. Your question says `Windows` equivalent, but you then refer to `bash`, which is `Linux/Unix` ?

Comment: Are you referring to `batch`?

Comment: Sorry, it was spelling mistake , I correct my word to batch.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without the sorting part, you can simply run this from cmdline or in a batchfile.

```
copy *.csv merged-file.csv
```

Which will copy the content of each csv file into `merged-file.csv`

To do the sorting and uniq part, you would need a little more than a simple oneliner.

Comment: thank you for your message, I have several files with the same columns name , I would like to remove them, that's why I am using all those commands with pip. In linux, this line will remove all the column names to one line and that's very easy.